# Handling database errors in sinatra

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra

I'm writing a Sinatra http-server with active-record. I'm using pg database to store data.

In this code I want to get all Cars from database with params (name, give them order, limit them) and I need to handle errors which are coming from the database.

For example if I ping '/cars' from curl:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/cars?attribute=error
```

I need the result:
    'Sorry, but there is no attribute with name error'

```
get '/cars' do    
  @cars = Car.order("#{params[:attribute]} #{params[:order]}").limit(params[:limit]).offset(params[:offset])
  @cars.to_json
 end
```

How can I handle exceptions which are coming from the database and display them to the user?

Comment: Welcome to SO! FIrst, don't send queries to the DB that a user can generate themselves or you run risk of being hacked. If `params[:attribute]` contained some sort of "delete everything" or "drop database" you'd have trouble. To check the result I'd send the validated query and see if I got nil and conditionally return the Sinatra error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check incoming attribute parameter

```
get '/cars' do   
  if Car.columns.map(&:name).include?(params[:attribute]) 
    @cars = Car.order("#{params[:attribute]} #{params[:order]}")
             .limit(params[:limit]).offset(params[:offset])
    @cars.to_json
  else
    { error: 'Sorry, but there is no attribute with name error' }.to_json
  end
end
```